# invalidoperationexception on actionresult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult

I'm trying to get some data from three database tables into a view. Therefore I use a class where I include two other classes with a List.

One of these two included classes works fine, but the other is causing an InvalidOperationException in a controller ActionResult.

This is what I've produced so far:

Classes

```
namespace ArrangeAppointments.Models
{
    public class Appointment : IAppointment
    {
        #region Implementation of IAppointments
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string Duration { get; set; }
            public virtual List<Invitee> Invitees { get; set; }
            public virtual List<Occasion> Occasions { get; set; }
        #endregion
        public int AppointmentId { get; set; }


namespace ArrangeAppointments.Models
{
    public class Invitee : IInvitee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AppointmentId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Presence { get; set; }
        public virtual Appointment Appointment { get; set; }


namespace ArrangeAppointments.Models
{
    public class Occasion : IOccasion
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AppointmentId { get; set; }
        public DateTime ocDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ocTime { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public virtual Appointment Appointment { get; set; }
```

ActionResult

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult NewApp(int Id)
{
    if (Id == 0)
    {
        return View();
    } else {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new MainDbContext())
            {
                Appointment appointment = db.Appointments.Find(Id);
                if (appointment == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("NewApp", appointment);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The object 'appointment' in the ActionResult is filled with all required data, except the List for Occasion. This causes the exception.
However, this exception does not trigger the catch event.

What's causing this exception ?

DbContext class

```
namespace ArrangeAppointments
{
    public class MainDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MainDbContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Invitee> Invitees { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Occasion> Occasions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: where does it throw the exception? are you using lazy loading ,show us the dbcontext class

Comment: I've added the DbContext class yet.

Comment: The only way I can see the exception is when I inspect the contents of the 'appointment' object when debugging the ActionResult.

Comment: Dont you need to include the lists ?  like , db.appointments.include("appointments.Occasions").include("appointments.Occasions").find(id);  reason for not throwing exception is that you dont access occasions

Comment: The 'Invitee' and 'Occasion' classes both include an 'Appointment' property, which returns the 'Appointment' object that both invitees and occasions relate to.

Comment: yes but to retrive that data you need to use keyword include to fill the lists it is not done automagicaly

Comment: @Thorarins Including the lists as suggested causes an error on the Find method.

Comment: Ok, but the data for Invitee is correct. That's why I get confused.

Comment: updated the code, you might also use FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the lists

```
 Appointment appointment = db.Appointments.include("Occasions").include("Invitees").SingleOrDefault(a => a.AppointmentId == Id);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Thorarins, for your expertise and your patience. It works fine now.